# Counting missing calls on iPhone/iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm quite new at iOS app development.
I'm starting to work on an app that should in somehow be able to count the missing calls that the iPhone has registered since the app is running.

I've read that in no way Apple is going to let me intercept incoming calls, answer them, reject them, or "whatever" them, but I wonder if we are allowed to count them.

I've found some people that say it can be done (well, I knew it is possible, cause LockInfo does, for instance), but I don't know if it's attached to jailbroken iPhones only.

Anyway, as far as I have seen, it must be done with some methods related to **kCTCallStatusChangeNotification** from ***CoreTelephony.h*** if I'm right (as seen in http://blogs.oreilly.com/digitalmedia/2008/02/when-it-comes-to-the.html), but I coudln't find much more info about it.

Comment: Actually, the libraries exist to intercept/answer/reject/count/etc. any and all incoming calls. However, using these *private APIs* will prevent your app from being accepted into the App Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello and welcome to iPhone Development! :) As you have already pointed out, you can be informed through a notification if a call is happening. Great! But here comes the dark side of iPhone Development:

**That's the end of the road.** 95% of the "Phone Functionality" of the iPhone is private API and you don't technically have access to it.

Of course, you could `header-dump` the private frameworks and use them anyway, but that will get your app instantly rejected from the AppStore, which wouldn't be fun for anyone.

LockInfo is an extension for **jailbroken devices** - those guys are known for not caring too much about Apple nor Private APIs ;) Also, as you may have seen, LockInfo isn't on the AppStore because it would've never made it that far.

So Apple, why is there `CoreTelephony`?

Well, it's there for some very specific reasons. I personally use it to obtain the carrier name of the device for certain country specific restrictions in my application. The notification you talked about, along with others, tend to be used by developers to prepare your app for going into an inactive state (when the call comes in, your app is put in the background), so its used to pause tasks etc... `CoreTelephony` has never been intended for any deep level access to the telephone system of the iPhone.

So sorry, you can't obtain the information you're looking for using public APIs.

Comment: Hi David! First of all:THANK YOU VERY MUCH! :) you are my first.. "answerer" (does that exist in English? :D )
Well, your words are very frustrating for me... In one hand, you told me that I can be informed if a call is happening. That would be "legal" for Apple? 
The idea of my application is quite simple: it will play a sound when you have your phone muted and you receive more than X calls, where X is a thresold you can set.
Maybe I should think of developing it for Cydia and jailbroken iPhones, but I'd prefer (for sure..) deploying it for Apple Store.. Isn't there anything I can do?
THANKS!

Comment: Most private APIs are written in plain C though (and some older ones from Mac OS X may also be in C++) so it'll be a bit difficult for a beginner to use private API. If you're up for a challenge though, google "header-dump iOS", there are some tutorials on how to do this. For me personally Cydia isn't that great, because the likelihood of your app being used illegally is huge. (jail breaking renders the system open, so everything is possible ;))

Comment: Thank you David... I think I'd better change my goal and try with any other app... :(
Best Regards!!